# Perl to find character and add second line after it finds text

Tags: perl

I am trying to get this script to work in regards to two find strings. I am having trouble getting the file to export the format I am looking for.

```
use strict;

my $find = '^(H0|HT)';

open (NEW, ">", "output.txt" ) or die "could not open:$!";
open (FILE, "<", "input.txt") or die "could not open:$!";

while (<FILE>) {
    chomp;

if (/^\h{39}\XX187/){
    print NEW join(",","$_\n");
}

if (/$find/){
    print NEW join(",","$_")
}
}
close (FILE);
close (NEW);
```

Input File:

```
                                                                                Txn Bch 
Account        Patient Name                                                         Date 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

HT12345678    TEST,TESTNAME                                                         01/01/16
                                  XX187         CLAIM PROCESSED                 01/01/16
```

Output File (Expectation):

```
HT12345678  TEST, TESTNAME    01/01/16    XX187     CLAIM PROCESSED 01/01/16
```

Comment: Is that the actual code you're running? `/^\h{39}\d/$find2/` should give a fatal syntax error.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to find the wording XX187 to be my next add line. is there something extra I am adding or should I change it to the word I am looking for such as    /^\h{39}\d/XX187/   ??

Comment: What is the `join(",", "$_\n")` for? There aren't any commas in your required output, and there is only a single item in your list so the result of the join is just `"$_\n"`

Comment: Do you really need `TEST,TESTNAME` converting to `TEST, TESTNAME`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very imprecise, and I'm having trouble understanding exactly what it is that you need. However, this short program may help

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

while ( <DATA> ) {
    print if /^(?:H[0T]|\s+XX187\b)/;
}


__DATA__
Account        Patient Name                                                         Date 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

HT12345678    TEST,TESTNAME                                                         01/01/16
                                  XX187         CLAIM PROCESSED                 01/01/16
```

#### output

```
HT12345678    TEST,TESTNAME                                                         01/01/16
                                  XX187         CLAIM PROCESSED                 01/01/16
```

Comment: sorry, I'm really limited the detail from the actual file due to personal information on the report. What I'm trying to do is copy the beginning with HT or H0 and then copying the next line there after that contains 39 whitespaces and the word XXX187 and copy that line as the added line to the line containing HT or H0. Hope that makes a little more sense.

Comment: @PhoenixJay: My answer does that.

Comment: If I want to utilize the $find how would I write the print?                          print if /^?:$find|\s+XX187\b/

Comment: Actually I got it to work with the $find.. Thank you very much @Borodin